# How to record multiple sequential fixed length clips?

Tags: guitar, recording, ableton-live

If I want to, say, record 24 bars of guitar, how can I pre set it up such that I can hands-free play all 24 bars and let it get recorded into 3 8 bars clips?

The closest I can think of is letting Ableton Push's fixed length be 8 bars and press down in the session view but it's really hard to operate while playing.

Comment: Would it work to record all 24 bars at once and the split that into three clips? It's not totally clear what you are trying to do. Also, are you aware of being able to use a foot pedal with Ableton Live?

Comment: I know about using foot pedals, though I don't think a foot pedal can have a single action that can end current clip + advance to the next clip + start recording next clip. The intent is to be able to finish playing the 24 bar and to seamlessly start using push to loop any of the 8 bar clips on push right away without having to use keyboard and mouse.